# Searching an array for a variable

Tags: matlab, matrix

How would I check if the string value of a specific variable is present in an array? I know `strcmp` and `ismember` are options, but how would I adapt these so they use the value of a variable to search in an array, as opposed to me typing in the string I want to search for. So my code will look something like:

```
C1 = {'red' 'yellow'};
C2 = {'green' 'blue'};
fn = 'blue';  

%Comparison function here

if % fn is present in C1
    c = 'm'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not understand what is wrong with `strcmp`, thus I am not sure I understood your question. Consider this

```
if any( strcmp(fn,C2) ) 
   disp('OK!')    % // OR  c = 'm'
end


OK!
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if any( cellfun( @(x) isequal(x, fn), C1 ) )
   c = 'm';
end
```

I believe you may also use `regexp`.

Comment: I think regexp is faster though :)